# Scikit-learn tutorial documentation location

Tags: python, ubuntu, scikit-learn

I have scikit-learn 0.16.1 installed on Ubuntu 14.04 and am working through the tutorial.  SKL was installed with all default configuration.  The tutorial states

> The source of this tutorial can be found within your scikit-learn folder:
>   scikit-learn/doc/tutorial/text_analytics/

I've used `find` on my entire drive and there is no "tutorial" folder. Not anywhere.  Anybody know where these files are really installed?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Installed via apt-get

Comment: Then you have used backports (or the neuro.debian repository)? (The package in Vivid is `Version: 0.15.1-1ubuntu1`)

Comment: I have the same problem.  Installed using homebrew on a mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Finding the package contents

Where the packages are installed depends on how you installed scikit-learn

- If you used Ubuntu's package system via

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python-sklearn python-sklearn-doc
  ```

  (you often need the doc package to get the accompanying documentation), then the tutorial is simply missing. The `doc/`-folder it is not contained in the `python-sklearn-doc`-package. See the [bug report](http:///usr/share/doc/python-sklearn-doc/html/index.html).

  You can find out the contents of the package via

  ```
  dpkg-query --listfiles python-sklearn-doc
  ```
- If you used [the Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) to [install it via](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html)

  ```
  pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn
  ```

  , then the installation should be at `$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn`. (as also of `pip show -f scikit-learn`) But a

  ```
  find . | grep -i tutorial
  ```

  did not find any `tutorial/`-folder.
- If you installed it from source, consider reinstalling via pip, as [the warning states that](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#from-source-package)

> Warning
>
> Packages installed with the python setup.py install command cannot be
>   uninstalled nor upgraded by pip later. To properly uninstall
>   scikit-learn in that case it is necessary to delete the sklearn folder
>   from your Python site-packages directory.

#### Solution

A solution would be to use the source. Either download the [master file](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/archive/master.zip) or do it via git:

```
    git clone https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

The git archive is more than 60 MiB, so you might want to prefer the [master zip](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/archive/master.zip).

Comment: docs are already installed: `python-sklearn-doc is already the newest version.
`

Comment: Thanks, the solution for me was to just download the entire master file and take what I needed for the tutorial.

Comment: You are welcome. What you did seems the best approach.